# c-program output

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

        FILE *fp,*fs;
        fs=fopen("c.dat","w");
        fp=fopen("c.dat","w");
        putc('a',fp);
        putc('1',fs);
        close(fs);
        close(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Irrespective of the order execution

```
 putc('a',fp);putc('1',fs);   


 putc('1',fs);putc('a',fp);
```

contents of c.dat is '1' only.
Can somebody explain the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, you don't `close()` a file that you opened with `fopen()`, you have to `fclose()` it. You're mixing two levels of abstraction here, file handles and file pointers.

On top of that, I think you'll find that the two file pointers are maintaining independent file offsets and buffers. Whichever one closes the file last will write their data last, overwriting the other.

Change the order of your `fclose()` statements and you should see what I mean:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    FILE *fp,*fs;
    fs=fopen("c.dat","w");
    fp=fopen("c.dat","w");
    fputc('a',fp);
    fputc('1',fs);
    fclose(fp);    // Try changing these
    fclose(fs);    //    two around.
    return 0;
}
```

I did that and consistently got the contents based on the last file closed.

And, before you say that you should have gotten `a` because `fp` was the last one you closed, you did *not* close `fp` (with an `fclose()`).

What you *did* do was try to `close()` a file handle that was almost certainly invalid, because file *handles* are generally relatively small values (e.g., `0`, `1`, `2`) while file *pointers* are generally relatively large values (e.g., `0xdeadbeef`, `0xcaf3f00d`).

So the closure of both those files was left up to the C runtime environment when you exited (and that would most likely have done it in a deterministic way, which is why you always got the same value in the file).

Comment: Yes problem is with close only...i corrected it now.And order of the execution  fclose(fp);fclose(fs); will affect the output because of buffering concept..........

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the same file for writing twice. All bets are off at that point.

Answer (score 1):

*You didnt specify the unerlying OS, but on win* and *nix systems file buffers are shared between processes, so :

```
    putc('a',fp); 
    putc('1',fs);
```

*are writing to exactly the same address in the same buffer
if you reversed the order of the putc statements you will end up with an 'a' in the file.**

### **NOT**

Just goes to show how tricky this all is. I have tried this and what affects the output is the order in which the files are opened -- the first open always takes precedence.

Comment: OP has already stated file contents are the same regardless of that order.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you opened c.dat through fs=fopen first and then some lock is not allowing "a" to be written, as it would require the file to be opened again.